# Python printing "<built-in method ... object" instead of list

Tags: python, printing

```
import numpy as np
arr = list(map(float,input().split()))
print(np.array(arr.reverse))
```

Why is this printing this instead of the contents of the list?

```
# outputs "<built-in method reverse of list object at 0x107eeeec8>"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first problem is that you are not actually *calling* the reverse method on your array `arr`.

You have this: `arr.reverse`

You have to actually call it -> `arr.reverse()`

Simple example below:

```
>>> [1,2,3].reverse
<built-in method reverse of list object at 0x100662c68>
```

Without calling `reverse`, the output you get is the uncalled reverse method of the `list` object. Which is very similar to the output you were getting.

The second problem you have is that `reverse()` method does the reverse in place, which means it performs the reverse on `arr` (your arr will be reversed) and returns `None`. So, when you are passing this:

```
np.array(arr.reverse())
```

You are returning the return of `arr.reverse()` to your `np.array` call, which is `None`.

So, fixing those two items, by calling `arr.reverse()` on its on, and *then* passing `arr`, will give you the result you are expecting:

```
import numpy as np
arr = list(map(float,input().split()))
arr.reverse()
res = np.array(arr)
print(res)
```

Demo:

```
1 2 3 4
[ 4.  3.  2.  1.]
```